# How to parse this type of XML(with data types) and read into a data table in C sharp

Tags: c#, datatable, xml-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loading XML String into datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682848/loading-xml-string-into-datatable)

```
string parseXML = "<TEST xmlns:dt=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes\">
                      <A dt:dt=\"string\">10</A>
                      <B dt:dt=\"string\">20</B>
                   </TEST>"
```

I learned that I can parse usual XMLs using ReadXml Command as shown in the [answer of my previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682848/loading-xml-string-into-datatable/12683162#12683162)

Comment: How is this different from your original question?

Comment: @cadrell0 In the first question, I was under the impression that ReadXml(reader) does the parsing for all the types of xmls, so my question was why ReadXml() is not working, and I got the answer saying it doesn't work for all kind of xmls, now my question is , what is the way to parse this particular kind of xml into datatable

Comment: I would say that the accepted answer on that question is not satisfactory.  While is does tell you why your code isn't working, it solves the problem the wrong way.  It tries to correct the problem with your data, rather than trying to correct the problem with your code.

Comment: That's a good point... I think I will keep that one open as well... I don't mind as long as I get the answer :)